# Is there any alternative to brute force matching binary images?

Tags: python, optimization, computer-vision, gpu, homography

This opencv/numpy code works, but is 1000x too slow. basically I have a white square, and another image that is slightly rotated and translated.  The code recovers the pose by brute force trying all angles and translations within 10 degrees and 10 pixels.

I tried find homography but got terrible results. This code got perfect results, but is far too slow. I need it to run 100 to 1000 times faster, while staying in python.

I would like to know how to massively speed up this code, or, an alternate way that recovers the fact that the image is rotated 5 degrees and translated about 5,7 pixels

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
import math
import time

# Create a 240x224 black image (image01) with a 64-pixel black margin
image01 = np.zeros((224, 240), dtype=np.uint8)
image01[64:160, 64:176] = 255  # Add a white square within the margin

# Copy image01 to image02
image02 = image01.copy()

# Rotate image02 by 5 degrees and translate it 5 pixels up and 7 pixels left
rows, cols = image02.shape
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols / 2, rows / 2), 5, 1)
M[0, 2] -= 7
M[1, 2] -= 5
image02 = cv2.warpAffine(image02, M, (cols, rows))

# Create scaled-down copies of image01 and image02
scaling_factor = 1/1
img1 = cv2.resize(image01, None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor)
img2s = cv2.resize(image02, None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor)

# Define parameters for the search
rotation_range = range(-10, 11, 1)
translation_range = range(-10, 11)

# Create a list to store the results
results = []

start = time.time()

for rotation_angle in rotation_range:
    # Rotate img2
    img2 = img2s.copy()
    M_rotation = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((img2.shape[1] / 2, img2.shape[0] / 2), rotation_angle, 1)
    
    img2_rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img2, M_rotation, (img2.shape[1], img2.shape[0]))

    for dx in translation_range:
        for dy in translation_range:
            # Translate img2_rotated
            M_translation = np.float32([[1, 0, dx], [0, 1, dy]])
            img2_transformed = cv2.warpAffine(img2_rotated, M_translation, (img2.shape[1], img2.shape[0]))

            diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2_transformed)
            non_zero_pixels = np.sum(diff[diff == 255])
            
            
            results.append((rotation_angle, (dx, dy), non_zero_pixels))

print(time.time() - start)
# Sort the results based on the number of non-zero pixels
sorted_results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[2])

# Show the top 10 results
for i, (rotation_angle, (dx, dy), non_zero_pixels) in enumerate(sorted_results[:10], 1):
    dx = dx/scaling_factor
    dy = dy/scaling_factor
    print(f"Top {i} - Rotation: {rotation_angle}°, Translation: ({dx}, {dy}), Non-zero pixels: {non_zero_pixels}")
```

the actual images look similar to this (random blobs)

[image]

Comment: If your images are just rotated white squares, can't you simply find the corners (i.e. fast min/max on rows/columns) and then use simple trig math?

Comment: Yes, like others said, basic rotation and translation are fairly trivial to correct for, just using math and trigonometry. If you provide sample images, I can give you a working code example. Edit: my bad, the "image" is provided in your code

Comment: @Julien no images are arbitrary thresholded depth images from a drone flying indoors at 1m with camera pointing down.  The goal is odometry.  So the images actually look like random blobs

Comment: Are there any memory limitations? For example, can we create images of 8000 patterns to be compared in advance and store them in memory?

Comment: can't you narrow down the search for best translation based on previous frame position and drone speed/rotation/etc.? Second thing - if blobs are large enough, you can first make coarse search with twice/thrise as big step, then do the fine search for most promising areas

Comment: @dankal444 yes you're right, but then i have to run that at faster fps to make smaller transforms. either way I need the code itself to be faster. seems lots of room for optimization from 'theoretical' standpoint.

Comment: @ken I'm actually interested in that kind of hi memory approach but the problem is the images are sequential so i only have one a short time before the next.

Comment: [mre] including input data required. and either give source data or give a really good justification as for why you expect us to solve your problem on *thresholded* data. -- what is this for? drones, these days, usually imply military applications or at least something that could be considered Dual Use.

Comment: odometry should be approached with optical flow or feature matching, or even SLAM. this should have surfaced during your research of this task.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz trust me, I'm very familar with that. turns out optical flow doesn't work very well on binary images. SLAM is almost always lidar based, and when it's image based it requires homography or ICP methods which require 'features', and it seems theres no good 'feature detector' for binary images. In any case I want this option as the 'baseline' but i'm sure it can be done at least 50x faster with better way to rotate/broadcast etc to compare more efficiently

Comment: I would use the Fourier-Mellin approach. Here’s a demo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100651/7328782

Comment: @AwokeKnowing I see. I am also curious why the square in your sample image seems to have a lower resolution than the blob above. This makes your problem more difficult and would cause degrade accuracy regardless of what algorithm is used.

Comment: @ken the square is the 'minimal reproducible example'.  The 'blob' represents an actual image and it wouldn't be matched with a square in that case, it would be matched with an near-identical image that is slightly rotated and translated.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sweet I'm going to try that and report back.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried to install diplib but got Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "11.8", but required is exact
  version "11.5" from cmake. can you update code or tell what to update to work for 11.8?

Comment: If you're using Python, just do `pip install diplib`. DIPlib doesn't use CUDA, so I'm not sure what that error is about.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did that first, but when I actually ran the code, the code that loads images gave error.  So i installed from source by just downloading the source and using cmake, and that's where i got the cuda error.  I guess I will make a separate question about that later today. Also, do you have a version that works on ARM like on Jetson nano?

Comment: We have a version for macOS on ARM platform (Apple Silicon), but not other platforms. But you can build it for any platform, I know at least one person has build it on a 32-bit ARM system. Please post issues about building on the GitHub repo!

Answer (score -3):

I'm in a bit of a rush so I post the code for finding the x,y offset:

```
def get_coords(array, locs):
    return np.array([array[i] for i in locs])

def find_center(img):
    ys, xs = np.nonzero(img)
    corner_indices = [np.argmin(xs),np.argmax(xs),np.argmin(ys),np.argmax(ys)]
    corner_xs = get_coords(xs,corner_indices)
    corner_ys = get_coords(ys,corner_indices)
    return np.array((corner_xs[:2].mean(), corner_ys[2:].mean()))# in (x,y) format

print(find_center(img2)-find_center(img1))
```

you can use similar formulas to find the rotation as well (will update the answer later today to include that)

Comment: this throws a bounding box on each image, then calculates the center of each bounding box...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Essentially yes, but the OP has changed the question to require 3D calculations. It's not that much more difficult to figure out the geometry using OpenCV contours and conversion to best fitting parallelogram and then figuring out the points and rotation angle/translation but I'm too busy to update the answer just now.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it's only 2D.  why do you say 3D? it's top-down birds eye view normalized to be flat from perspective of camera, so tracking is almost perfectly 2D and the question is specifically about the 2D case